# How to make time in specific format from current timestamp in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a time stamp like 2014-05-26 16:39:32 . From this time stamp I want to make something 4:39 PM , 26thMay 2014 . Is there any built in function to this ? Or how can I do it ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php This might help you

Comment: You can try momentjs: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @FarizAzmi JS is not PHP

Comment: The function you want is `date`. It takes a format string that tells it how to format the date and time.

Comment: `echo date('g:i A dS F Y', strtotime('2014-05-26 16:39:32'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo date('h:i A, dS M Y', strtotime('2014-05-26 16:39:32')); // 04:39 PM, 26th May 2014
```

without leading zero in time try  `4:39`

```
echo date('g:i A,dS M Y', strtotime('2014-05-26 16:39:32')); // 4:39 PM, 26th May 2014
```

For more read manual:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('g:i A,dS M Y',strtotime('2014-05-26 16:39:32'));
```

For more you can look into [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in php

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`DateTime`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class like this

```
$a = new DateTime("2014-05-26 16:39:32");
echo $a->format("h:i A, dS M Y");
```